# How can I keep my Wifi connection from shutting off when I connect radios with a NIC?

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking

I work as a Motorola tech and have a laptop with Windows 10. When I hook up radios, most of the time, they have some networking component for [IP Site Connect](https://www.motorolasolutions.com/content/dam/msi/docs/business/product_lines/mototrbo/mobiles/_documents/english/staticfiles/mototrbo_ip_site_connect_extend_your_reach__improve_your_performance.pdf) or what have you. Once my computer sees the network interface in one of these, it kicks me off Wifi, supposedly deferring to that device for internet access.

How can I stop this from happening? If it's not a setting that can be set for the Wi-Fi connection itself, I'm going to have to do something for each individual network device it sees. I'm up to like 200 generic network devices right now from programming so many radios for work.

I've been able to defer this for so long because if I have a wired ethernet connection, that will stay connected. But that doesn't help me when I am out in the field doing radio programming.

Comment: Have you asked your IT Administrator for assistance?

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/on-topic specifies: _What topics can I ask about here?  Super User is for computer enthusiasts & power users. If you have a question...  and it is not about … issues specific to corporate IT support and networks..._ so because IT is involved, I'm afraid this is a question we can't tackle.

Answer (score 0):

Try to prioritize the wireless adapter by setting its metric to the
lowest value, which is `1`.
The lower the metric number means higher priority or lower "cost".

Windows 10 calculates an automatic value for the metric, but this can be
overridden as described below.

- Open *Settings > Network & Internet > Status*
- Click *Change Adapter options*
- Right-click the wireless network adapter and select *Properties*
- Select "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)"
- Click the *Properties* button
- In the "General" tab, click the *Advanced* button
- Clear "Automatic metric"
- Set "Interface metric" to `1`
- Click *OK* twice and *Close*
- Reboot.